# Browser not sending any data (no errors)

Tags: websocket, faye, bayeux

So I have a faye server and a rails web application. It all worked fine till recently. Now the browser is not sending anythin to the server. There a no error not on the server not even in browser (I can create an instance of Faye.Client just fine). But when I do publish the server gets nothing. It doesn't even get anythin on the meta channel, like connect or subscribe. The thing is that if I send something with curl the server shows the message (cause I'm logging it).

I can't pin point the problem. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. The url to which faye was connecting was not OK, but faye failed silently because the url responded. :/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the code to send messages is being reached. Make sure your client is still valid. Test an earlier code version etc. Just a few ideas.